# Multiple Instances of the same app are generated in stack

Tags: android, app-launcher

If there is an app has a login activity, and it launches by the icon click. this login activity can be launched by another intent too. the problem is when the activity is running, (launched by touching the app icon) and when it receives the different intent call it starts another login activity.

how can i launch the login activity again after closing the current running activity, when the different intent call is received to launch the login activity.
the different intent mentioned above is, when the user select an specific file with specific extension, my app must be started.

```
<activity
        android:name=".login.Login"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data
                android:scheme="content"
                android:mimeType="application/octet-stream"
                android:pathPattern=".*\\.chat"
                tools:ignore="AppLinkUrlError" />
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>
```

The second intent is called , my app downloads the selected file and stores it in internel storage.
 this is the onCreate method in the Login Activity

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    if (getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.portrait_only)) {
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_NOSENSOR);
    } else {
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
    }
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    if (isTaskRoot()) {
        Uri data = getIntent().getData();
        if (data != null) {
            getIntent().setData(null);
            try {
                importData(data);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // warn user about bad data here
                finish();
                return;
            }
        }
    }

 ...................................

}
```

when user selects a specified file, the app launches another activity. then there are two login activities in the stack. help me to get rid of this

singleinstance,  singletask solutions were tried. but when the launchingmode is set to singleinstance or singletask and the second intent call is received it does not call the

> importData()

method. so the file that i want to download is not downloaded..

Comment: try to add `android:launchMode="singleInstance"` in manifest file in  activity tag

Comment: tried. then  one login activity is launched . but when the specified file is selected as mentioned above the importData() method is not called. now no two login activities are in the stack

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I used "singleTask" as launchMode. Then I have to use onNewIntent() when the Activity is called again. below link gives some more Explanation.

[“onCreate()” method is not called from another intent filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53588183/oncreate-method-is-not-called-from-another-intent-filter)